I can't compile a C project in Termix on android, what should I do?
I'm trying to compile this C code project : https://github.com/msantos/sods
it seems successfull using Ubuntu, Debian, Kali Linux and the others, but in Android on Termux it doesn't succeed as when I execute the make command, I get an error that libresolv.a is not found, I have realized that libresolv.a exists only in some Linux extensions like Debian, but it's not the same situation for android, the configure file doesn't even have a specific configuration for android, and now I'm confused because I didn't find an alternative for this libresolv.a in android, any solutions?
I have tried to get help from ChatGPT but it didn't help me as I expected.
EDIT
to be more clear here is what I have done in Termux :
pkg install git
git clone https://github.com/msantos/sods.git

then I went to the sods client folder "sdt"
cd sods/sdt

then I have executed the configure file
./configure

it generates the required Makefile of the operating system "Linux" but of the normal linux, not linux of android.
then when I execute
make

the compilation returns with error that libresolv.a doesn't exist
here is the configure file :
#!/bin/sh

OS=`uname -s`

case $OS in
    'Linux')
        if [ -e /usr/lib/libresolv.a ]; then
            STATIC_LIB=/usr/lib/libresolv.a
        else
            STATIC_LIB=/usr/lib/*/libresolv.a
        fi
        DEF="-DHAVE_ERRX"
    ;;
    'Darwin'|'NetBSD')
        DEF="-DHAVE_ARC4RANDOM -DHAVE_ERRX"
        LIB="-lresolv"
    ;;
    'OpenBSD')
        if [ ! -e /usr/local/lib/libbind/libbind.a ]; then
            echo "Please install libbind: sudo pkg_add libbind"
            exit 1
        fi
        DEF="-DHAVE_ARC4RANDOM -DHAVE_ERRX"
        LIB="-L/usr/local/lib/libbind -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib/libbind -lbind -I/usr/local/include/bind"
    ;;
    'FreeBSD')
        if [ ! -e /usr/local/lib/libbind.a ]; then
            echo "Please install libbind: sudo pkg add libbind"
            exit 1
        fi
        DEF="-DHAVE_ARC4RANDOM -DHAVE_ERRX"
        LIB="-L/usr/local/lib -lbind -I/usr/local/include/bind"
    ;;
    'SunOS')
        if [ ! -e /opt/local/lib/libbind.a ]; then
            echo "Please install libbind: sudo pkg_add libbind"
            exit 1
        fi
        DEF="-DHAVE_ERRX"
        LIB="-lsocket -lnsl -L/opt/local/lib -Wl,-rpath=/opt/local/lib -lbind -I/opt/local/include/bind"
    ;;
    *)
        echo "Guessing, adjust Makefile by hand ..."
        LIB="-lresolv"
    ;;

esac

if [ -e /dev/urandom ]; then
    DEF="${DEF} -DHAVE_URANDOM"
fi

cat<<EOF>Makefile
CC ?= cc
RM ?= rm
APP=sdt

STATIC_LIB=${STATIC_LIB}
DEF=${DEF}
LIB=${LIB}

all:
        \$(CC) \$(DEF) -g -Wall \$(LIB) \\
    -Wall -Wextra -pedantic \\
    -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-qual \\
    -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes \\
    -I../common \\
    -o \$(APP) \$(APP).c \$(APP)_dns.c \$(APP)_err.c \$(APP)_rand.c base32.c ../common/strtonum.c \$(STATIC_LIB) \\
    -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now -Wl,-z,noexecstack

clean:
        -@\$(RM) *.o \$(APP)
EOF

and here is the Makefile:
CC ?= cc
RM ?= rm
APP=sdt

STATIC_LIB=/usr/lib/*/libresolv.a
DEF=-DHAVE_ERRX -DHAVE_URANDOM
LIB=

all:
        $(CC) $(DEF) -g -Wall $(LIB) \
    -Wall -Wextra -pedantic \
    -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-qual \
    -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes \
    -I../common \
    -o $(APP) $(APP).c $(APP)_dns.c $(APP)_err.c $(APP)_rand.c base32.c ../common/strtonum.c $(STATIC_LIB) \
    -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now -Wl,-z,noexecstack

clean:
        -@$(RM) *.o $(APP)

and here is the make command output error :
cc -DHAVE_ERRX -DHAVE_URANDOM -g -Wall  \
    -Wall -Wextra -pedantic \
    -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-qual \
    -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes \
    -I../common \
    -o sdt sdt.c sdt_dns.c sdt_err.c sdt_rand.c base32.c ../common/strtonum.c /usr/lib/libresolv.a \
    -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now -Wl,-z,noexecstack
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/usr/lib/*/libresolv.a'
make: *** [Makefile:10: all] Error 1


Did you use NDK clang compiler? You have to provide the correct build addresses that compiler sees headers and library binaries.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@ImanAbdollahzadeh I don't think that NDK is necessary because I'm already trying to compile the project inside android itself, but I tried to install NDK anyways and use it but the same thing, I tried to use the libresolv.a taken from a ubuntu machine, others errors appears, and this issue happens only with "sdt" side, the "sods" and "ds" sides just requires to remove "-lresolv" from Makefile to work on android
